# Everything apt related failes after changing kernal

Tags: apt, surface

```
sudo apt update
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian/ release: /var/lib/extrepo/keys/surface-linux.asc != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.

sudo apt install -f
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian/ release: /var/lib/extrepo/keys/surface-linux.asc != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

And so on... Everything apt related results in these two errors. I just recently followed this github page for surface pro 8: https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup

I used extrepo during the install but that was after I had already tried the manual install method first. After using extrepo it somehow worked, now I can use everything on my surface pro... exept apt no longer works. please help... finals are coming up and I need to finish installing Packet Tracer. :)

here is the error for the packet tracer install:

```
dpkg: error processing package packettracer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packettracer
```